# Programatically search multiple PDF documents for a series of keywords

Tags: pdf

**The Problem**

I have 500+ PDF files which I need to search for instances of a set of keywords and score how many times each keywords from each set is used within the file (ideally to be dumped into a CSV file).

For example I could have the following

```
keyword-set-1 = "foo" "bar";
keyword-set-2 = "jon" "doe";
```

and a PDF file with the following text

```
"jon doe and mary doe are both at the bar."
```

Which would give me the following score

```
keyword-set-1 = 3 (jon, doe and doe)
keyword-set-2 = 1 (bar)
```

**What I have done already**

I have found multiple ways I could do this in PHP or Java if I was searching a plain text file. However I haven't found a single solution for a PDF file. I have considered converting all the PDF's to plain text using PDF miner, however I would prefer to avoid this if possible.

The PDF's are high quality, not scanned forms.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify what the quality of the PDF is? Are they scanned forms? Then you might need to use OCR. I can recommend Tesseract (also requires an image converter like ImageMagick), which converts the PDF to a HTML file. You can then easily loop trough the words using Jsoup.

If it is not scanned you can use PDFBox. This is also a Java library.

Tesseract: https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/
PDFBox: http://pdfbox.apache.org/